# adding one view contoller as a child of another view controller in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I need to know how to add one view contoller as a child of another view controller in objective-c. 
     As of now I am presenting a view controller as a modal of the rootview controller. But I want to change it now. I have 2 view controllers which I am presenting as modals of root view controller. But how can I present them in a different way?  How does this parent-children concept work?  Please give me some references.

Comment: It might help if you were a little more specific about what you're trying to achieve. There are a number of ways of presenting views in iOS. If you can cite some examples we may be able to provide links to tutorials that address your needs specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you should read the following:

[View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/)

I believe that between the two of them you should be able to learn most, if not all, of what you need to learn about UIViewControllers and view hierarchys.

Comment: The second link is outdated and not very relevant anymore due to the concept of child view controllers introduced in iOS 5. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html